# Upgrade MVC5 project to MVC6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

In one of these days I would like to start with a new project and MVC seems really interesting, but I was wondering if it is possible to upgrade a MVC 5 project to a MVC 6 project, which will be released later this year?

Or do you have to start all over again since a lot of things have been changed? Or do you recommend me to wait until MVC 6 is released?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It won't be a direct upgrade path, as a lot of breaking changes were made. You can start playing with MVC 6 now though, no need to wait. You can download the [Visual Studio 2015 Preview](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs) and get started.

Some of your code will move over, but you'd need to go through and verify every bit of it and fix a lot of errors. It's probably better to start from the ground up with MVC 6 (Microsoft has recommended this in some Q&A on videos I've seen).

#### Edit 11/28/2015

Visual Studio 2015 is officially out now, and ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6 are in RC1 status. You can create a new ASP.NET 5 project with MVC 6, then just copy over all the source files. After that, work though the errors one by one until you've solved them all.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. So it will be fine when I reuse the project from VS 2015 Preview in the final VS 2015?

Comment: Probably not. If VS 2015 was finished, it wouldn't be called "Preview". But the point is that you can get started now and then handle changes in the framework as they happen, and give feedback to the team to make sure the final version works the way you want it. So the question you have to ask yourself is "Do I want to work on the fancy nice new thing, even though things may change and I might have to make a few adjustments?" or "Do I want to use the old version of the framework which isn't as nice and will require a lot of rework to upgrade?"

Comment: This is not an official response, right? I guess later MS may offer an upgrade wizard to do this job...

Comment: @ChrisTorng What do you mean "offer an upgrade wizard?" They can't make a wizard that can write your code for you. And that's what would have to happen in order to upgrade from MVC 5 to 6. Breaking changes were made, decisions have to be made on how to do things. You shouldn't trust a machine to do that for you. But for the most part, the main logic of your application should transfer. Copy the code from an MVC 5 project into a clean MVC5 project, then go through the errors one by one until you've got it working again.

Comment: I "guess" later MS "may"... Only my guessing, it may or may not happen. They can make a wizard that do this job if they really wish you to upgrade current project. Just like they did it for VB6 "upgrade" to VB.NET before. Although the upgrade is only partial, but at least it can reduce those stupid errors that easy upgrade can help.

Answer (score 2):

***Migrating From ASP.NET MVC 5 to Core MVC***

> This article shows how to get started migrating an ASP.NET MVC project
>   to ASP.NET Core MVC. In the process, it highlights many of the things
>   that have changed from ASP.NET MVC. Migrating from ASP.NET MVC is a
>   multiple step process and this article covers the initial setup, basic
>   controllers and views, static content, and client-side dependencies.
>   Additional articles cover migrating configuration and identity code
>   found in many ASP.NET MVC projects.

Here is the URL: **[Migrating From ASP.NET MVC 5 to Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/mvc)**

Comment: The link is there.But now there is no MVC 6.It is now ASP.net core MVC. @ErikPhilips