# Can current RTMed ASP.NET MVC 5 project run on .NET Core to run in Linux?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linux, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-core

According to [Upgrade MVC5 project to MVC6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760455/upgrade-mvc5-project-to-mvc6), upgrade RTMed MVC 5 project to MVC 6 is hard, then the next question is: Can current RTMed ASP.NET MVC 5 project run on .NET Core to run in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET 5 cannot run on CoreCLR on Linux yet. The only option for now is Mono.

Comment: I found another version problem... As I know, current RTMed ASP.NET version is 4, but MVC version is 5. Next previewing version for ASP.NET is 5, MVC is 6... So my problem is about: current RTMed ASP.NET MVC 5 project, not previewing ASP.NET 5 project.

Comment: CoreCLR (on Windows) supports ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6. MVC 5 cannot run as part of the ASP.NET 5 stack. Sorry if that's confusing. MVC is currently one version ahead of the framework.